# Drools decision tables -- calling functions inside value cells

Tags: drools

I am looking to use drools decision tables for a project. I want to add a condition where I verify that the value of a passed in object is less than a specified number. I want the decision table to look something like:

[image: http://imgur.com/gf1Twb4]

If you look at the third condition where I am checking the max size of the loan, I am calling a function: `$t.getStandardLimit($n).`

Unfortunately, I am unable to call the function inside the value cells with that syntax (drools reads it as a string and returns a syntax error). Is there a way to do this?

UPDATE: The solution was to add $param in the condition check (loanAmount <= $param)

Comment: Please post images inline instead of linking them externally.

Comment: Is it missing the semicolon at the end? And post the the error message you're getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have not actually tested it but I think it may work:

for the Max loan condition, change it to `loanAmount <= $param`.

If loanAmount is of type integer or double etc, it should work without problem because, after subtituting $param, both  `loanAmount <= $t.getStandardLimit($n)`  and `loanAmount <= 1000000` is a valid expression.